# Unclosed GSP expression in grails 2.0.3 although it's closed

Tags: java, grails, gsp, grails-2.0

I created this grails view (create.gsp) for my event Instance but after calling /event/create i get the following error message (stacktrace):

```
   Line | Method
->>  19 | runTask in /grails-app/views/event/create.gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

Caused by GrailsTagException: Unclosed GSP expression
->>  33 | doCall  in /grails-app/views/event/create.gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

This is my create.gsp:

```
<%@ page import="testProject.Event" %>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="backend">
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'event.label', default: 'Event')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.create.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="speedbar">
       <div class="speedbar-nav"> <a href="#">Color life Admin Panel</a> › <a href="#">Form Styling</a></div> 
       <div class="search">
             <form>
              <input type="text">
             </form>   
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-1" id="create-event">
    <!-- Line 19--> <g:if test="${flash.message}">

            <div class="alert blue hideit message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
        </g:if>
        <g:hasErrors bean="${eventInstance}">
                <g:eachError bean="${eventInstance}" var="error">
                <div class="alert red hideit"><g:message error="${error}"/></div>
                </g:eachError>
        </g:hasErrors>
           <div class="title-grid"><g:message code="default.create.label" args="[entityName]" /><span></span></div>
           <div class="content-gird" style="display: block; ">
           <div class="form">
            <g:form action="save" >
                    <g:render template="form"/>
                    <g:submitButton name="create" class="button-a gray" value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" />
            <!-- Line 33--> </g:form>
             <div class="clear"> </div>
             </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where is my mistake? Do you see it?

Comment: could you please highlight the line number in code

Comment: i added the line numers 19 and 33 as code comment in html

Comment: hmm wierd.. may be you could try again by grails clean, also check for double quote used, try removing them and type from your keyboard once

Comment: What is inside template `form`?

Comment: Problem fixed. The mistake was in the _form.gsp, because there was a small misstype in the scaffolding template! Thank you guys! :-)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in GSP error reporting in Grails 2.0.3 . This commit might have fixed it: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/commit/fbb46af1aac77dd215eae7a1625f830fc2b1cb29

Please re-test the GSP error reporting with Grails 2.1.0 RC1 version and if the problem remains, report the problem in Grails Jira with a test case. That would help improving the GSP error reporting. Thanks!